What is 'ḍukr̥ṅkaraṇ'?
In the Moha Mudgara stotra by Shankaracharya, the sage advices an old man practising the rules of Paninian grammar in the streets of Varanasi to let go of all this, and worship Krishna.
His advice is the well-known Bhaja Govinda stotram.
It goes like this-
bhaja govindaṁ bhaja govindaṁ
govindaṁ bhaja mūḍha-mate |
samprāpte sannihite kāle
nahi nahi rakṣati ḍukr̥ṅkaraṇe ||
Now, I get the rest, but what is ḍukr̥ṅkaraṇ?
Is it something related to grammar? A rule of grammar? If yes, could you tell me the rule/an elaborate meaning of the word?
